# No return value from function with if statment

Tags: c++

How can I return from a function if a condition is not met.
I'm trying to make a division function and it will return the result of dividing 2 numbers, but if its division by zero how do I return nothing.

```
int div(int n1, int n2)
{
    if (n2 > 0)
    {
        return n1 / n2;
    }
}
```

I get this warning when compiling:

> warning: control reaches end of non-void function

I understand what it means, but what should I put in case n2 was 0 if I dont want to return a value;

Comment: If you don’t want a return value in that case, what *do* you want? What should the caller of your function get?

Comment: `throw` an exception?

Comment: use std::optional<int> and return std::nullopt in "else"

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you want to happen? We get that you don't want to return a value. What do you want to do?

Comment: I'm new to C++ so I don't really know whats the correct thing to do. what should I return in this case.

Comment: If you think the show must go on, you can return `infinity` or `max int`.

Comment: There is no *correct* thing to do.  There are *many* different ways you can approach this issue, each has its advantages and disadvantages. Use whatever way suits your needs.

Comment: invalidArg exception is the way to go here

Comment: Another option is returning `NaN`

Comment: @Kao, is there a `NaN` for integers?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Nope there isn't. Thanks for the detail. So let me update my proposal, for `float`ing point division returning `NaN` can be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a function has a return type, it MUST return *something*.  So, you can either:

Return a sentinel value that the function and caller agree on to represent a "non-value", eg:

```cpp
int div(int n1, int n2)
{
    if (n2 != 0)
    {
        return n1 / n2;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1; // or whatever makes sense for your use-case...
    }
}
```

If there is no sentinel value available that you can use, then you can use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) instead (C++17 and later only), eg:

```cpp
#include <optional>

std::optional<int> div(int n1, int n2)
{
    if (n2 != 0)
    {
        return n1 / n2;
    }
    else
    {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
}
```

Or, you can change the function to use an output parameter and a `bool` return value, eg:

```cpp
bool div(int n1, int n2, int &result)
{
    if (n2 != 0)
    {
        result = n1 / n2;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you will just have to `throw` an exception instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>

int div(int n1, int n2)
{
    if (n2 == 0)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("n2 must not be 0");
    }
    return n1 / n2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation.